# Configuring app.yaml for AppEngine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'd like to configure my site as follows for SEO purposes:

```
site.com       -> main.php
site.com/X     -> script1.php
site.com/*     -> script2.php
site.com/*/*   -> script2.php
site.com/*/*/* -> script2.php
```

where * is any value apart from X.

How do I set up my app.yaml so that this works. I've tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
- url: /X.php
  script: script1.php

- url: /*/*
  script: script2.php

- url: .*
  script: main.php
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found is:

```
- url: /X
  script: script1.php

- url: /X\/.*
  script: script2.php

- url: .*
  script: main.php
```

Comment: Not sure if this truly reflects your question, where script2.php is supposed to respond to /<any pattern other than X>/.* as well?